# how to handle ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) using try and except

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I was solving problem:
Fuel gauges indicate, often with fractions, just how much fuel is in a tank. For instance 1/4 indicates that a tank is 25% full, 1/2 indicates that a tank is 50% full, and 3/4 indicates that a tank is 75% full

```
while True:
    # enter input: e.g. 1/3
    exp = input("fraction: ")
    x, y = exp.split("/")
    l = ((int(x) / int(y)) * 100) #converts value into percentage
    try:
        v = round(l)
        if v>=99 and v<=100:
            print("F")
            break
        elif v<=1:
            print("E")
            break
        elif v>100:
            pass
        else:
            print(f"{v}%")
            break


    except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError): #supposed to handle value error and...
        pass
```

but for input 5-10 the program is supposed to be passed.(since "/" is ,missing) but instead I am getting this error message: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) using try and except

Comment: The line that raises the error, `x, y = exp.split("/")`, is not inside your try/except?

Comment: You are trying to get two value out of split, but 5-10 cannot be split so it only return one value, that's why you got that error, you didn't catch it in try.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get two value out of split, but 5-10 cannot be split so it only return one value, split is not included in the try catch so the error stopped your program.

Simply move the try upward would do the trick

```
while True:
    # enter input: e.g. 1/3
    exp = input("fraction: ")
    try:
        x, y = exp.split("/")
        l = ((int(x) / int(y)) * 100) #converts value into percentage
        v = round(l)
        if v>=99 and v<=100:
            print("F")
            break
        elif v<=1:
            print("E")
            break
        elif v>100:
            pass
        else:
            print(f"{v}%")
            break

    except ValueError:
        print("ValueError")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("ZeroDivisionError")
```